# Can I tell who is accessing archive.org archived documents from my site from my server logs?

Tags: web-crawlers, cache, nginx, internet-archive

I currently host a website with a collection of some of my projects, where a few of them are currently undergoing a patent review process. I don't want these documents to be public (though they were in the past), so I've deleted the documents on my website. However, they are still available on the Wayback Machine's archive.org. The Wayback Machine has informed me that they do not store who has accessed certain URLs, but they can remove my page from the archive if I request it.  Is there a way that I, through my own server logs, can see that these old, since-deleted documents are being accessed? My backend collects access logs, for the record.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The wayback machine stores its own copy of the page, so browsers dont interact with your server when viewing the archived version (thats the point of it.. if your site changes or goes away there is still a record)